1H NMR of phosphonic acid
I am working on synthesis of an alkyl bromide from alcohol by action of $\ce{PBr3}$.  The product has a limited solubility in DCM, thus isolation by filtration of the product seems to be a better option to an aqueous work up.  However, the product is contaminated with an impurity having singlets in $\ce{^1H}$ NMR at 7.53 and 5.92 ppm (DMSO-d6).  Can these signals be a doublet of the phosphonic acid's proton with $\ce{^1J_{PH}}$ = ~644 Hz?  Instrument frequency is 400 MHz.
To clarify: (a) what is the chemical shift of PH in phosphonic acid? and (2) is $\ce{^1J}$ coupling close to 644 Hz? A reference to literature will work Thanks.

It's unlikely to be a splitting due to a J coupling (644 Hz is extraordinarily large). Single bond CP couplings can reach a little over 100 Hz (check publications).

Thank you, Buck.
My assumption was based on data from this forum and some other sites:
1JPH of PH3 = ~175Hz.
1JPH of HP(O)(OMe)2 = ~1200Hz  - this Forum:  The magnitude of 1H-31P couplings varies enormously, depending on bond order, oxidation state of 31P and bonding arrangement.
1JPH of HP(O) = ~630Hz      from http://sopnmr.ucsd.edu/coupling.htm

You're right, that's impressive. I guess that reduces the main question to whether the chem shift is correct. Check also that the integrals of the two peaks are close to equal.

The described peaks do not appear to match phosphonic acid.
In addition to Buck Thorn's comment that the peak separation to too large to likely be a doublet, we also note that the P-H hydrogen of phosphonic acid would likely appear at lower shift, close to what we would see for an alkyl hydrogen. The P-H hydrogen is bonded to a nonmetal with relatively low electronegativity and can be expected to show hydride-like character (thus lower chemical shift) due to pi back-donation from the electron-rich oxygen atoms.
